# Admob banner location

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add AdMob to my app. The ad appears at the top of the screen, but I want the Ad to be shown at the bottom of the screen instead. You can see my code in the following image. What's wrong?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzoYa.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Hi, you should try searching SO for question that may be similar to yours. See if the answers given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39539699/how-to-put-admob-banner-to-bottom-of-the-screen-using-coordinatorlayout solves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use RelativeLayout as parent layout and use android:layout_below property in child i.e ad use [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) for reference

Comment: thanks for reply, I fix it. How I can remove the title bar? I also tried;

requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

but doesn't work

Comment: you can remove from manifest.xml for details ask separate question and if it helped in previous question pls select my answer